# Comparing two arrays of objects and updating lastSeen based on id in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, object

I have two arrays of user objects with _id and lastSeen.

```
allUsersSeen = [
   {_id: '12csdf', lastSeen: 212512},
   {_id: '232csdf', lastSeen: 34345},
   {_id: '1253csdf', lastSeen: 6346453},
   {_id: '772csfddf', lastSeen: 2345345}
]

currentUsersSeen = [
   {_id: '12csdf', lastSeen: Date.now()},
   {_id: '1253csdf', lastSeen: Date.now()},
   {_id: '1fsdf', lastSeen: Date.now()}
]
```

I want to compare these two arrays and if the allUsersSeen _id matches to currentUsersSeen I want to update lastSeen to Date.now(). All other _id's will keep its lastSeen to what it was.

Any remaining _id from currentUsersSeen should be pushed onto allUsersSeen with a lastSeen of Date.now()

Final array of allUsersSeen should look like:

```
allUsersSeen = [
   {_id: '12csdf', lastSeen: Date.now()},
   {_id: '232csdf', lastSeen: 34345},
   {_id: '1253csdf', lastSeen: Date.now()},
   {_id: '772csfddf', lastSeen: 2345345},
   {_id: '1fsdf', lastSeen: Date.now()}
]
```

Obviously the Date.now()'s will be the current date/time.
How would I go about doing this?
I've tried using a nested for loop and tried messing around with forEach() and map().

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You should post what you tried and how it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this,

```js
allUsersSeen = [
        {_id: '12csdf', lastSeen: 212512},
        {_id: '232csdf', lastSeen: 34345},
        {_id: '1253csdf', lastSeen: 6346453},
        {_id: '772csfddf', lastSeen: 2345345}
    ];

    currentUsersSeen = [
        {_id: '12csdf', lastSeen: Date.now()},
        {_id: '1253csdf', lastSeen: Date.now()},
        {_id: '1fsdf', lastSeen: Date.now()}
    ];

    function merge(a, b, prop){
        var reduced =  a.filter( a_item => ! b.find ( b_item => a_item[prop] === b_item[prop]) )
        return reduced.concat(b);
    }
    console.log( merge(allUsersSeen, currentUsersSeen, "_id") );
```

Comment: Yes, this was perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like that

```
allUsersSeen = [
   {_id: '12csdf', lastSeen: 212512},
   {_id: '232csdf', lastSeen: 34345},
   {_id: '1253csdf', lastSeen: 6346453},
   {_id: '772csfddf', lastSeen: 2345345}
]

currentUsersSeen = [
   {_id: '12csdf', lastSeen: Date.now()},
   {_id: '1253csdf', lastSeen: Date.now()},
   {_id: '1fsdf', lastSeen: Date.now()}
]

let newArr = allUsersSeen.map(user => currentUsersSeen.find(curr_user => curr_user._id === user._id) || user);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you understand what you're trying to do, you can achieve that by pretty much removing the element from allUsersSeen (if present) first and then adding it again from currentUser.

```js
allUsersSeen = [
   {_id: '12csdf', lastSeen: 212512},
   {_id: '232csdf', lastSeen: 34345},
   {_id: '1253csdf', lastSeen: 6346453},
   {_id: '772csfddf', lastSeen: 2345345}
]

currentUsersSeen = [
   {_id: '12csdf', lastSeen: Date.now()},
   {_id: '1253csdf', lastSeen: Date.now()},
   {_id: '1fsdf', lastSeen: Date.now()}
]

currentUsersSeen.forEach(user => {
  allUsersSeen = allUsersSeen.filter( obj => obj._id != user.id )
  allUsersSeen.push(user)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `array#concat` both the arrays and then use `array#reduce` to update the `lastSeen`.

```js
var allUsersSeen = [{_id: '12csdf', lastSeen: 212512},{_id: '232csdf', lastSeen: 34345},{_id: '1253csdf', lastSeen: 6346453},{_id: '772csfddf', lastSeen: 2345345}],
    currentUsersSeen = [{_id: '12csdf', lastSeen: Date.now()},{_id: '1253csdf', lastSeen: Date.now()},{_id: '1fsdf', lastSeen: Date.now()}],
    
    result = Object.values( allUsersSeen.concat(currentUsersSeen).reduce((r, {_id, lastSeen}) => {
      r[_id] = r[_id] ? {...r[_id], lastSeen} : {_id, lastSeen};
      return r;
    },{}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```